# Is it possible to use model's @property decorators with Model.values()?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a model with the following fields and decorators:

```
class Item(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=100)
    thumb = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    vendor = models.CharField(max_length=15)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    views = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    @property
    def parsed_thumb()
        return = self.url + "/static/" + self.thumb
```

which I query in a class based view with:

```
results = Items.objects.filter(title__icontains=query).order_by('-views')[offset:limit].values('id', 'url', 'title', 'vendor', 'thumb')
```

The problem is the call to `values()` returns db fields and, as far as I know, has no way of interacting with @property decorators that belong to the Items model.

I need the return value from `parsed_thumb()`. What are my options?

Comment: Are you sure you need to use `values()`? Why not use a regular queryset and access the property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querysets are there to interact with the database, where as properties are only accessible to model. You could annotate the property to work with the queryset using [Concat](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#concat), but this won't be using the property

```
results = Items.objects.filter(title__icontains=query).order_by('-views')
results = results.annotate(parsed_thumb=Concat('url', Value('/static/'), 'thumb'))[offset:limit].values('id', 'url', 'title', 'vendor', 'thumb', 'parsed_thumb')
```

Comment: I like this solution, it works for the problem I had, so I'll mark it as correct. Unfortunately, I'd simplified the problem so I could explain it easily. I also have other fields that need to be converted from binary to decimal, as well as other modifications. I quickly tried to expand your answer to work for my other problems like so: 
`results = results.annotate(dec_num=self.bin_to_dec(bin_field))` but it looks like I can only use the Django Database Functions from the link you provided. Still, thanks for providing a good answer to the question I did ask.

Comment: @Sam - You might struggle (See [Django custom annotation function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30416270/1324033)). The answer here suggests use extra but there are big warnings about using extra in the django docs.

Comment: Yeah, the more I look at this problem, the more I realise how messy it could get. I really don't want to use `extra()` for obvious reasons.

Answer (score 1):

If you have such simple method you can try to use [QuerySet.extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.extra)

```
results = Items.objects.extra(
    select={'parsed_thumb': "url || '/static/' || thumb"}
).filter(title__icontains=query).order_by('-views')[offset:limit].values(
'id', 'url', 'title', 'vendor', 'thumb', 'parsed_thumb')
```