# fuzzy search in django postgresql without using Elasticsearch

Tags: django, postgresql, fuzzywuzzy

I try to incorporate fuzzy serach function in a django project without using Elasticsearch.

**1- I am using postgres, so I first tried levenshtein, but it did not work for my purpose.**

```
class Levenshtein(Func):
    template = "%(function)s(%(expressions)s, '%(search_term)s')"
    function = "levenshtein"

    def __init__(self, expression, search_term, **extras):
        super(Levenshtein, self).__init__(
            expression,
            search_term=search_term,
            **extras
        )
```

```
items = Product.objects.annotate(lev_dist=Levenshtein(F('sort_name'), searchterm)).filter(
                            lev_dist__lte=2
                        )
```

Search "glyoxl" did not pick up "4-Methylphenylglyoxal hydrate", because `levenshtein` considered "Methylphenylglyoxal" as a word and compared with my searchterm "glyoxl".

**2. `trigram_similar` gave weird results and was slow**

```
items = Product.objects.filter(sort_name__trigram_similar=searchterm)
```

- "phnylglyoxal" did not pick up "4-Methylphenylglyoxal hydrate", but
  picked up some other similar terms: "4-Hydroxyphenylglyoxal hydrate",
  "2,4,6-Trimethylphenylglyoxal hydrate"
- "glyoxl" did not pick up any of the above terms

**3. python package, fuzzywuzzy seems can solve my problem, but I was not able to incorporate it into query function.**

```
ratio= fuzz.partial_ratio('glyoxl', '4-Methylphenylglyoxal hydrate') 

# ratio = 83
```

I tried to use `fuzz.partial_ratio` function in `annotate`, but it did not work.

```
items = Product.objects.annotate(ratio=fuzz.partial_ratio(searchterm, 'full_name')).filter(
                            ratio__gte=75
                        )
```

Here is the error message:

```
QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s): 12.
```

According to this stackoverflow post ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30416270/django-custom-annotation-function)), annotate does not take regular python functions. The post also mentioned that from Django 2.1, one can subclass `Func` to generate a custom function. But it seems that `Func` can only take database functions such as levenshtein.

Any way to solve these problems? thanks!

Comment: You can not use `partial`, since the annotations do *not* run at the Django/Python level. What the Django ORM does is *construct a **database** query*. A function like `Levenshtein` is thus only some mechanism to write `levenshtein(sort_name)`, etc. in the *query*, not evaluate it at the Django/Python level.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Thank you for the quick response. Any idea how I should implement fuzzy search then?